# Best way to join group .mp3 files together

Tags: mp3

I have more .mp3 files such as :

> t001.mp3 t002.mp3 t003.mp3 .....
>
> e001.mp3 e002.mp3 e003.mp3 .....

I would like to merge :

```
t001.mp3 and e001.mp3 ->>>> r001.mp3
t002.mp3 and e002.mp3 ->>>> r002.mp3
t003.mp3 and e003.mp3 ->>>> r003.mp3
```

something like this.

What is the best way to do this command? have an application or batch command?

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Linux you can simply use `cat file1 file2 > file3` command to concatenate the files and get merged mp3 file which would play the above in sequence.

Similar functionality is available in other Operating Systems including Windows eg: (`type file1 file2 > file3`) as well.

More info is available in the following related question.

[Using cat to join mp3 files. What is this black sorcery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222225/using-cat-to-join-mp3-files-what-is-this-black-sorcery)

Cheers!!!

Comment: and how about window platform?

Comment: and it doesn't hurt to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've use [MP3Wrap](http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/), a command-line tool, successfully. It can be used at the comand prompt or in batch files. Some commands for its use:

```
mp3wrap  combinedfiles.mp3  file*
```

To wrap all the files in a directory:

```
mp3wrap combinedfiles.mp3 *
                or
mp3wrap combinedfiles.mp3 *.*
```

Two or more files:

```
mp3wrap combinedfiles.mp3 file1.mp3 file2.mp3 etc.
```