# Joining many of [two mp3] files into many [one] file

Tags: mp3

I hope good luck to you.

Anyways, 
I have separate mp3 files. ("A" mp3s and "B" mp3s)

**I want to join two mp3 files into a single pair.**

**The problem is, there are too many pairs that needs to be made.**

Is there any software available to this kind of task?

(I know ‘mp3 joiner’ software, but it’s useful when you make MANY files into ONE file.)

In short, what I’d like to do is:

A01.mp3, B01.mp3 => A01+B01.mp3

A02.mp3, B02.mp3 => A02+B02.mp3

A03.mp3, B03.mp3 => A03+B03.mp3

A04.mp3, B04.mp3 => A04+B04.mp3

A05.mp3, B05.mp3 => A05+B05.mp3

....
....
....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222225/using-cat-to-join-mp3-files-what-is-this-black-sorcery?rq=1)

You can join 2 mp3 files by combining them as `cat file1.mp3 file2.mp3 > out.mp3`

As thats left to do is to take a programming language of your choice to issue the cat commands one after another.