# Concatenate audio files [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, audio, pygame, built-in

**Is** there any way to concatenate or merge two audio files into one?

**Requirements** : Must use built-in modules only [may use PyGame]

**Audio File format** : .wma OR .wav OR .mp3

I have looked at many questions now and found solutions that involved downloading modules (which I do not prefer).

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: did you try to search for it? pydub: http://pydub.com/ ?

Comment: i did and i found the process of installing very tedious

Comment: then define "appropriate solution", please

Comment: can't you use ffmpeg?

Comment: you are right @MaxU, i'll make some changes to the framing of the question!

Comment: Why not just cat the files? :)

Comment: if i do that won't the wav header pose a problem after all i am talking about audio and not text files

Comment: @qwerty well it worked fine for the two mp3s I just tested

Comment: so how do you cat two audio files?

Comment: `cat file1.mp3 file2.mp3 > merged.mp3`. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222225/using-cat-to-join-mp3-files-what-is-this-black-sorcery - mp3s seem to be a bit special.

Comment: where should i write that command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make some research and found this.

```
#import libraries
from glob import iglob
import shutil
import os
#create path variable
PATH = r'C:\music'
#create everything.mp3
destination = open('everything.mp3', 'wb')
for filename in iglob(os.path.join(PATH, '*.mp3')):
    shutil.copyfileobj(open(filename, 'rb'), destination)
#make them all together with for
destination.close()
#close file
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001538/how-do-i-concatenate-files-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to join two Flac files by just concatenation as long as the two files were produced by the same encoder:

```
audio1 = open("audio1.flac", "rb").read()
audio2 = open("audio2.flac", "rb").read()
audioJoin = audio1 + audio2
audioFinal = open("audioFinal.flac", "wb").write(audioJoin)
```